# Detecting an arbittrary button press on a USB joystick WITHOUT pygame

Tags: python

Is there anyway I could register button pushes on a joystick without using any function from pygame?

Comment: Look through the PyGame source; think about how you use joystick functionality in PyGame and follow the code until you find what you want. Or look at file names and you'll probably find what you want.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for a way to do it without writing an extension library for Python (which is what `pygame` is).

Comment: @Amber: I'm suggesting that he see how PyGame does it; it may be in native Python for all I know.

Comment: Pygame propably just delegates to the SDL code for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to do it with just the standard Python library, the answer is probably "no" - or at the very least, "not in any straightforward manner". There are many things in the standard library, but gaming hardware support is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If your on linux, you could check out [Python Joystick Class using Gobject](http://www.jezra.net/blog/Python_Joystick_Class_using_Gobject)